# can I use munge SDP sample to connect with another PC?

Tags: c, webrtc

So I wanted to create peer for webrtc in C, but I still don't quite get how the connection is made. I wanted to use the https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/munge-sdp/ sample generating a SDP file in my computer, change the IP4 field (so i don't just do a loopback), put it in offer, do the same in another computer (to put in answer) [basically i'd do the signalling myself] to connect.

i tried it over my local network, but i failled miserably.

here is one of the SDP files

```
`
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-52.4.0 7301737099351893139 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 29:C1:12:C2:D7:03:B6:A8:E1:28:DC:DC:DE:A5:A0:0E:A8:D4:3A:CF:D5:67:9A:6B:4A:38:8C:DE:9C:ED:4E:D8
a=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0 sdparta_1 sdparta_2
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:1/sendonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ice-pwd:f0fa540801b8b01d2616d465cdbaf888
a=ice-ufrag:23f84f96
a=mid:sdparta_0
a=msid:{518019eb-2799-4525-ac2f-486dc4eb8ef4} {ebd29374-a915-41f1-868f-a5bca57540c1}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:3747370289 cname:{5339d74a-cea8-4286-9a6f-5c6682f03b4a}
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 121
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=ice-pwd:f0fa540801b8b01d2616d465cdbaf888
a=ice-ufrag:23f84f96
a=mid:sdparta_1
a=msid:{518019eb-2799-4525-ac2f-486dc4eb8ef4} {38ff8810-1ae3-4786-b95c-e945f649f032}
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:8090718 cname:{5339d74a-cea8-4286-9a6f-5c6682f03b4a}
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:f0fa540801b8b01d2616d465cdbaf888
a=ice-ufrag:23f84f96
a=mid:sdparta_2
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 256
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:3024981980 cname:{5339d74a-cea8-4286-9a6f-5c6682f03b4a}
```

`

obs: i left the IP4 as 0.0.0.0 on purpose
obs2: I missed the ICE candidates, but not sure

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

no you can not. To connect to another PC you need a signaling server and exchange things like ice ufrag/pwd and the dtls fingerprints. Take a look at https://appr.tc/

Comment: do you know of any other in which i can see the SDP file?

Comment: Doing the signaling manually wouldn't put an end to this lack of signaling server?